# Verificar o type com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom tenho dois botões em um formulário, sendo eles:

```
<button type='reset' onclick="history.back()">CANCELAR</button>
<button type='submit'>ok</button>
```

Tenho o seguinte jquery que identifica o clique no botão e envia o formulário:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {

            // Envia formulário
            $("form").submit();

    });
});
```

Preciso que o `$("form").submit();` senha executado apenas quando o botão clicado for `type='submit'`.

é possível fazer isso com jquery?

Comment: Um botão `type='submit'` já faz submit do form. Parece-me que estás a usar jQuery sem necessidade? ou esta é uma versão reduzida do teu código?

Comment: Esta em uma versão reduzia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use um [seletor de atributo](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$("button[type=submit]").click(function () {
   $("form").submit();
});
```

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida, como submeter apenas o formulário que o botão corresponde? Tenho algumas página que possui mais de um formulário, é possível fazer o botão identificar qual o formulário que ele esta e o enviar?

Comment: @HugoBorges por padrão um botão do tipo `submit` já submete o form em que está inscrito. Porém caso você queira fazer isso por jquery, podes fazer [**assim**](https://jsfiddle.net/nage574f/2/), usando o método [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Comment: para vc entender melhor o que estou fazendo vou postar o código mais completo, https://jsfiddle.net/t5wmdkwp/5/ . Estou tentando fazer com que o botão fique desabilitado por 2 segundos. porém o `prop('disabled', true)` impede o envio do `form`, eu resolvo isso com o `$("form").submit()` só que o botão envia apenas o ulmo `form` sendo que ele tem que enviar o `form` que pertence ao botão. Entendeu melhor meu problema?

Comment: Bom o `closest.` resolveu o problema. Olha como ficou. https://jsfiddle.net/t5wmdkwp/9/ Mais uma vez, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que alterando o tipo do botão de `reset` para `button` já seja o suficiente, o código ficaria desta maneira:

```
<type='button' onclick="history.back()">CANCELAR</button>
```

Comment: acho que vc não entendeu bem a pergunta.